# Basic CSS problem - parent DIV with unknown child DIVS, centered parent DIV

Tags: css

When i'm centering a DIV i will give it a width and put `margin:auto` on it, however i have two problems with this situation.

1. There are going to be either 2 or 3 DIVS inside this parent DIV with float:left on them. The width of the child DIVS won't change but the number might (2 or 3).
2. This therefore means i cant put a width on the parent DIV through not knowing the number of DIVs inside.

sample markup:

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

So in summary, i need to have the parent DIV centered with the DIVs inside floated left.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/qk4dW/

```
.wrapper {
    text-align:center;
}
.parent,.child {
    display:inline-block;
}

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It should work.

Comment: It's always worth adding the proviso, and reminder, that "[IE 6/7 accepts the value {of `inline-block`} only on elements with a natural display: inline.](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#t03)."

Comment: Well this is perfect for me, a great technique i'll be using in the future!

Comment: inline-block is very useful but be careful with IE<8 (thanks David)!