# Middle align three spans in a div (varying heights)

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

OK given this markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<span class="left"></span>
<span class="middle"></span>
<span class="right"></span>
</div>
```

`.left` and `.right` are fixed heights, but `.middle` will be varying height.

So i need it to look like this:

`-!!-` rather than `_!!_` which it is by default.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: would all span contain only text or other elements ?!

Comment: two outer spans contain hyperlinks, middle one contains an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the answer you were [given yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159085/basic-css-problem-parent-div-with-unknown-child-divs-centered-parent-div/7159113#7159113).

Basically, just add `vertical-align: middle` to the elements with `display: inline-block`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/qk4dW/1/ - or [here](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/qk4dW/2/) for identical code but with the middle element tallest.

```
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
.left, .middle, .right {
    vertical-align: middle;

    display:inline-block;
    /* if you need ie6/7 support */
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}
.left, .right {
    height: 100px
}

div {
    border: 1px solid #f0f
}
```